# SAP HANA Studio's Remote Source has stopped working

Tags: hive, odbc, hana, unixodbc

My Hive's remote source in SAP HANA Studio Has stopped working. The image below shows it:

[image]

The error that shows is the following:

> SAP DBTech JDBC: [403]: internal error: Cannot get remote source objects: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified

In SAP HANA machine, I have the next configuration in `/etc/odbc.ini`:

```
[HIVE]
Description=Hortonworks Hive ODBC Driver (64-bit) DSN
Driver=/usr/lib/hive/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64/libhortonworkshiveodbc64.so
HOST="My AWS IP instance"
PORT=10000
Schema=default
ServiceDiscoveryMode=0
ZKNamespace=
HiveServerType=2
AuthMech=3
ThriftTransport=1
UseNativeQuery=0
UID=hive
PWD=hive
KrbHostFQDN=_HOST
KrbServiceName=hive
KrbRealm=
SSL=0
TwoWaySSL=0
ClientCert=
ClientPrivateKey=
ClientPrivateKeyPassword=
```

When I try to run isql, it runs successfully and I can run queries successfully too. The image below shows it:

[image]

What could be the error?

Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to check that the ODBC.ini for the adm OS user is still configured correctly. `"Data source name not found"` sounds a lot like `"there is no ODBC.ini entry for that"`.

Comment: Finally, I have could to solve the problem searching all odbc.ini files in the system and writing the HIVE DNS configuration in all of this. I think SAP HANA wasn't pointing to odbc.ini file that I thought.